# Explode and Set if condition php

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 )
```

I'm trying to set an `if` condition based on user permission, the idea is to show menu based on given values, if it is 1, one menu will be displayed and 2 second menu will be displayed, if its both then all values will be displayed. So far for single values i have gotten it right but how to do it for array of values 
This is my code

```
<?php
   $userid = $this->phpsession->get("user_id");
   $userrole = $this->phpsession->get("user_type");

   $query = $this->db->select("role_empid,role_permissions")->from('hw_role')->where('role_empid', $userid)->get()->result();
   $data = $query[0]->role_permissions;

   if($data == 1){
?>
      <li><a href="<?php echo base_url("enquiry/addEnquiry"); ?>">Add Enquiry</a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo base_url("enquiry"); ?>">Enquiry List</a></li>
<?php }else if($data == 2){ ?>
       <li><a href="<?php echo base_url("enquiry/proposalList"); ?>">Request For Proposal</a></li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Look at `in_array` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: ok @fubar can you share an example

Comment: what is the value in "role_permissions" if it contain multiple value array or json?

Comment: Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 )  value of role permission @PoonamNavapara

Comment: What is the issue with your current condition?

Comment: @Sachin i wanted to show both menus when it contains an array of values

Answer (score 0):

if role_permission contain json object that first convert it into the array like

```
$data = $query[0]->role_permissions;
$data=json_decode($data);
```

otherwise direct check the condition for

```
$data = $query[0]->role_permissions;

if(in_array(1,$data) && in_array(2,$data))
{
}
else if(in_array(1,$data))
{
}
else if(in_array(2,$data))
{
}
```

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given

Comment: Yes, $data must be contain array value

Comment: what should i do then?

Answer (score 0):

If `$query[0]->role_permissions` is an array that has distinct value, then you can try :

```
       <ul>
       <?php for($i = 0; $i<count($data);$i++) {
       if($data[$i] == 1){ ?>

       <li><a href="<?php echo base_url("enquiry/addEnquiry"); ?>">Add Enquiry</a></li>
       <li><a href="<?php echo base_url("enquiry"); ?>">Enquiry List</a></li>

       <?php }
        if($data[$i] == 2){ ?>

       <li><a href="<?php echo base_url("enquiry/proposalList"); ?>">Request For Proposal</a></li>

       <?php }} ?>
       </ul>
```

Comment: when it have array value of Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 ) only enquiry list is shown, i need both menu to be shown when it contains 1 and 2

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<?php
  if(in_array(1,$data)){
?>
     <li><a href="<?php echo base_url("enquiry/addEnquiry"); ?>">Add Enquiry</a></li>
     <li><a href="<?php echo base_url("enquiry"); ?>">Enquiry List</a></li>
<?php }
  if(in_array(2,$data)){ 
?>
     <li><a href="<?php echo base_url("enquiry/proposalList"); ?>">Request For Proposal</a></li>
<?php } ?>
```